# invalid subscript type 'list' with lapply in WeightedCluster

Tags: r, lapply, traminer

I have a data frame that I split into different subsets. Based on that I generate lists of  sequences and the 
distance matrices, followed by a hierarchical cluster analysis.

```
library(TraMineR)
library(WeightedCluster)
library(cluster)

data(mvad)
value1 <- min(grep('\\d{2}$', names(mvad)))
value2 <- max(grep('\\d{2}$', names(mvad)))
mvad.split <-  split(mvad, f=mvad$male)



mvad.seq   <-  lapply(mvad.split,  function(x){seqdef(x[value1:value2])})
mvad.om    <-  lapply(mvad.seq,    function(x){seqdist(x, method='OM',
                                               indel=1, sm='TRATE')})
mvad.dis   <-  lapply(mvad.om,     function(x){as.dist(x)})
mvad.hc    <-  lapply(mvad.dis,    function(x){hclust(x,
                                               method='ward.D2')})
```

Then I want to convert my hierarchical clustering list into a seqtree list with the sequence data and distances

```
mvad.tree  <-  lapply(mvad.hc,     function(x){as.seqtree(x,
                                                     seqdata=mvad.seq[[x]],
                                                     diss=mvad.dis[[x]],
                                                     weighted=F,
                                                     nclust=6)})
```

And get `Error in mvad.dis[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'`. 
My actually data consists of many cohorts and the use of split() combined with lapply() would save me a lot of time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO!, without test data it is not possible to reproduce the error, I would suggest to have a look at [how to post a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and adding some test data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the last `lapply`, each element comes from a node in `mvad.hc`, hence are hclust objects. You don't want to `lapply` on this list but on the list of names and get corresponding object. Something like:

```
mvad.tree <- lapply(as.list(names(mvad.hc)), FUN=function(name){
  as.seqtree(mvad.hc[[name]],seqdata=mvad.seq[[name]],
  diss=mvad.dis[[name]],weighted=F,nclust=6)})
}
```

Not tested as we don't have data (cf. comment).

Comment: I changed mvad.tree[[name]] into mvad.hc[[name]] and this works. Thanks for the help Eric!